# Error:duplicate files during packaging of APK

Tags: android, opencv, android-studio, build, android-ndk

I am using OpenCV with Android Studio. I have a C++ module with ndk and java part. As it says in tutorial I placed opencv libs under `...src\main\jniLibs` direcotry. When I buld my C++ code with ndk-build it generates the lbraries under `..src\main\libs` folder ans so I have the following error:

```
Error:duplicate files during packaging of APK D:\AndroidStudioNDKProjects\Inpainting\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug-unaligned.apk
    Path in archive: lib/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_java3.so
    Origin 1: D:\AndroidStudioNDKProjects\Inpainting\app\src\main\jniLibs\armeabi-v7a\libopencv_java3.so
    Origin 2: D:\AndroidStudioNDKProjects\Inpainting\app\src\main\libs\armeabi-v7a\libopencv_java3.so
```

What I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem is that you include 2 lib with same name and android is a bit racist about this (even if both are the same library). one may came from your c++ module and the other from your java part

basic solution : follow your dependencies and remove the extra library.

i would say, just remove the one in "jniLibs. but hard to be more precise without your project under the eyes....

Comment: I thought that jniLibs is the default directory from where java part will search for opencv, but I just remove from there as you suggest and it seems to work. Thank you.